# What is the good way for user message display

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

i wonder about a clean way to display messages (ie error, warning, info) to end user, when messages are coming from the EventBroker.
Currently I'm using a hidden part, which handles enventBroker messages this way:

```java
/**
 * Handle the {@link EventTopics#ERROR_OCCURED} topic. Displays a simple
 * error dialog.
 * 
 * @param userDialogDescriptor
 * @param shell
 */
@Inject
@Optional
private void notifyUserForError(
        @UIEventTopic(EventTopics.ERROR_OCCURED) UserDialogDescriptor userDialogDescriptor,
        @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell) {

    IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, Activator.ID,
            userDialogDescriptor.getReason());
    ErrorDialog.openError(shell, "Error",
            userDialogDescriptor.getConsequence(), status);
}
```

Is it possible to trigger message display (and Shell grab) in a cleaner way, without using a "fake" and hidden part?

I tried to write a simpler handler with @UIEventTopic annotation, without success.

Comment: Have you tried using an AddOn instead of the Part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StatusReporter` (`org.eclipse.e4.core.services.statusreporter.StatusReporter`) to report errors anywhere without having to send messages:

```java
@Inject
StatusReporter reporter;

...


reporter.show(IStatus.ERROR, "message", any associated exception);
```

You can also use status reporter to log and show errors:

```java
IStatus status = new Status(....);

reporter.report(status, StatusReporter.LOG | StatusReporter.SHOW);
```

Comment: I was not aware of StatusReporter, thanks for that. By the way, error messages i'm displaying may come from services that have no dependencies on e4 (plain OSGi services). So they cannot use StatusReporter..